# How do i use for loop for this code so,the class element changes?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use for loop this code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="machine1"]').forEach(p => {
  if (p.textContent === '') {
    p.textContent = partnumber;
    jobsheets();
  }
})
```

so, it changes to machine 2, or machine 3. Stops once it reaches machine 3.

Comment: Are you trying to only change the `.textContent` of the first two elements of the `NodeList`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: sorry about that im new to stackflow. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const machines = [1,2,3];

machines.forEach(function(m) {
    document.querySelectorAll(`[class^="machine${m}"]`)...
})
```

Define the machines you want to loop through, and then loop through them, changing your selector each time

Comment: If OP is only trying to set the `.textContent` of a single element `.querySelector()` can be substituted for `.querySelectorAll()`, else another loop would be necessary to iterate `document.querySelectorAll(\`[class^="machine${m}"]\`)`